# Android remove test keys and shared keys in aosp source

Tags: android, android-source, android-tv, android-build

How can i remove test keys and shared keys in aosp source.

When i execute native root checker in my android device it shows error in test keys and shared keys and says the device is rooted. I need to build a rom with test keys and shared keys removed and also make my device a unrooted one.

Answer (score 0):

By default in AOSP in path `build/target/product/security` there are some *global* keys ( everyone has them). You're supposed to generate your own and replace them. See this [link](https://source.android.com/devices/tech/ota/sign_builds#release-keys) for the documentation.

Or instead of replacing them, you can specify the folder to your own keys in order to override them e.g.:

```
PRODUCT_DEFAULT_DEV_CERTIFICATE  :=  $(PRODUCT_DEV_INTERNAL_CERTIFICATE_DIRECTORY)/releasekey
PRODUCT_VERITY_SIGNING_KEY := $(PRODUCT_DEV_INTERNAL_CERTIFICATE_DIRECTORY)/verity
```

As for the root, maybe you are making a `userdebug` or `eng` build that has `su` and the ability to run `adb root`